# Blue highlight in achievements view

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

The blue highlight in the achievements view in the Android app appears to be behaving unpredictably. I opened the view four times in succession to see recent reputation gain. The first and fourth times the reputation gain was highlighted, the second and third times it was not. This is already after I had previously clicked on it.

App version is 1.0.82. Device is Samsung Note 5, Android version 5.1.1.

> [image: highlight on achievement]
>
> <sup>The "Left multiplication isometry?" is highlighted for unknown reason</sup>

Comment: I couldn't repro it on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app 1.0.82 (beta). In fact, I couldn't make the blue highlight show at all even after trying 10+ times... maybe I need to wait for another rep change, but meanwhile, could you provide your device model and Android version?

Comment: @Andrew added the info.